# c# - Get specific value or posistion of selected spinner item

Tags: c#, spinner

I have a problem.

I created a spinner with some customers. The spinner was built from a list that had 4 columns: Id, Name, Age, Gender. In the spinner I created items that looked like this: 
**Id: 1 - Name: John - Age: 46 - Gender: Male

Id: 2 - Name: Micheal - Age: 32 - Gender: Male**
Etc.

Now what I want is to get the Id of the selected item, but I can't figure it out, because I created a custom item string. So when I want the input, I get of course the whole string. How can I only get the Id of the string and cut off the: **"Id: => - Name: ... - Age: ... - Gender: ..."** So the only thing that is left is the Id as an **Int**?

```
private void CustomerSpinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
    SelectedSpinnerCustomer = spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
    LoadCustomerInfo(SelectedSpinnerCustomer);
}
```

So just to be clear, I want the **SelectedSpinnerCustomer** to be an int. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create a custom Spinner class that inherits the regular spinner class and contain all four of you properties

```
public class MySpinner : Spinner
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the event

```
private void CustomerSpinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    MySpinner spinner = sender as MySpinner;
    int SelectedSpinnerCustomer = spinner.Id;
    int age = spinner.Age;
    string name = spinner.Name;
    string gender = spinner.Gender;
}
```

Comment: What do I need to do in the `private void CustomerSpinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)`?

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are several different methods in the `string` class that you could use for this. Here is one that's a bit simplified and use a variety of string methods.

```
//Save the string in a local variable with a short name for better readability
string str = spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();

//Split the string by the underscores ('-')
string[] splitted = str.Split("-");
//Now you have a string array with all the values by themselves
//We know that ID is the first element in the array since your string starts with the ID
//So save it in a new string
string idStr = splitted[0];
//idStr is now "id: x "
//Remove the spaces by replacing them with nothing
idStr = idStr.Replace(" ", "");
//idStr is now "id:x"
//To get only 'x' we need to remove "id:" which can be done in multiple ways
//In this example I will use String.Remove() method
//Start at index 0 and remove 3 characters. This will remove "id:" from "id:x"
idStr = idStr.Remove(0, 3);
//Now idStr is "x" which is an integer, so we can just parse it
int id = int.Parse(idStr);
//Now you have the id as an integer!
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!